# link/button formatting for a post method in rails 3.2.4+

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this code is throwing an error during the page render because it isn't finding the route for this link:

```
<li class="link">
    <%=link_to "Save current options to a cluster", division_clusters_path(@current_dvision, courses: @cluster_courses ), :method => :post unless @cluster_courses.empty? %>
</li>
```

It worked in an older 3.2 copy, but upon upgrading past 3.2.4 it starts throwing an error because it is looking for a GET route when only a POST route exists (it is meant to go to a standard create method).

I switched it from a link_to to a button_to and tried to explicitly hash out the URL options from the HTML options to prevent ambiguity but I am still screwing something up.

I am assuming if the button_to is bombing, that I am doing something incredibly wrong. I am just not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's falling back to a GET request suggests that the `:method => :post` is not making its way into the options argument:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb, line 231
def link_to(*args, &block)
  if block_given?
    options      = args.first || {}
    html_options = args.second
    link_to(capture(&block), options, html_options)
  else
    name         = args[0]
    options      = args[1] || {}
    html_options = args[2]
    .....  
  end
end
```

Since the precedence of the `unless` operator is greater than method invocation, that leaves `division_clusters_path(@current_dvision, courses: @cluster_courses )` as a possible culprit.  If that is returning something that is swallowed by args[1], then args[2] would get the rest of the options (which are meant for args[1]).  By the way, it looks like there is a typo there: `@current_dvision`.

Comment: Thanks, That was an embarrassing lesson (it was the typo). I hand typed out all the checks to verify the data being passed to the link so I was seeing what I expected to see. I assumed it was ambiguous link parameter formats because that is my most common mistake when it comes to link_to type stuff. Sorry & thanks :)